# Marginal Surfaces in Spacetimes

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime

Is there some result on existence of marginal surfaces in spacetime 4-manifolds?

Am I right in saying that a marginal surface (like a trapped surface) is a compact spacelike 2-surface by definition, so if we assume a spacelike hypersurface embedded in the manifold, does that mean that there has to be a marginal surface contained in that hypersurface, or is there some other weaker existence result?

Comment: I am certain the proper term is *marginally trapped surface* (and *marginally trapped tube* for the 3D object) not just marginal surface.

Comment: Are you asking about results that give you conditions under which such surfaces exist (or are formed)? Or are you asking about a result that states that such surfaces exist in every space-time? The way you've written the question suggests that it is the second possibility, which of course is false.

Comment: Sorry, I meant is that is a result giving conditions under which marginally trapped surfaces exist in a spacetime?

Comment: The short answer is yes. Have you done a quick search on the web?

Comment: Yes, I searched and found several papers by Andersson.